# Random data generated in columns

Tags: r

I am trying to generate data based on a column as input to a function. I need three columns a1, a2, a3 instead of list as shown below. Also, I need to round of these numbers. Any suggestions?

```r
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(a = 1:10)
data$a %>%
  purrr::map(function(x) rnorm(3, x, 1))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1.513705 1.543769 1.840468
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1.183428 2.256548 1.991634
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3.584815 1.917402 2.905785
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 2.402710 4.358808 3.723491
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 3.310686 5.035873 4.886036
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 5.419101 5.911897 5.610797
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 7.813963 6.818650 7.836421
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 7.967020 7.284805 8.346075
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 8.407555 8.242997 7.525530
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 11.775647  9.573505  9.672808
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind_rows` will combine these vectors, by row into a dataframe. They need to be named first, which is why `setNames` is used. Those names then become the column names in the output.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(a = 1:10)
data$a %>%
  purrr::map(function(x) setNames(rnorm(3, x, 1), paste0("a", 1:3))) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows() %>% 
  round(1)
```

**Output**

```
      a1    a2    a3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   2.4   0.9   1.4
 2   1.9   0.6   1.6
 3   2.6   2.9   4.1
 4   4.8   3.8   3.7
 5   5.7   5.6   4.3
 6   5.3   6.4   6.8
 7   6.9   7.9   7.4
 8   7.4   8.3   6.9
 9  10.4  11     8.6
10   9    10.6   9.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Full credit to @LMc; Marginally less typing:

```r
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)

data = data.frame(a = 1:10)

data$a %>%
  map_dfr(function(x) set_names(rnorm(3, x, 1), paste0("a", 1:3))) %>% 
  round(1)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       a1    a2    a3
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1   0.4   0.8   2.6
#>  2   2.1   2.1   3.7
#>  3   3.5   1.7   2.3
#>  4   3.6   5.2   4.4
#>  5   5.4   5.1   4.4
#>  6   7.8   6.5   4  
#>  7   7.7   6.5   5.9
#>  8   7.8   7     7.3
#>  9   8.4   7.3   9.8
#> 10  10.2   8.9  11.3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>